# Specific time trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have tables with information about bank accounts transactions where i have the id account number, balance, date and users of any transactions. Everytime i deposit or withdraw money, the account balance of a specific account changes (obviously). I need to create a trigger who sum all the account balances, like a total balance of all of them at the end of the day and fill another table with every specific day and each total balance. I think i should use that trigger but i dont know how to filter that by day.

```
CREATE TABLE movement
(account    VARCHAR(10)        NOT NULL ,
date       TIMESTAMP          NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
description VARCHAR(30)        NOT NULL,
type      ENUM('D','W')      NOT NULL,
value      DECIMAL(7,2)       NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE balance
(account       VARCHAR(10)     PRIMARY KEY,
balance        DECIMAL(7,2)   NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE daily_balance

(date DATE PRIMARY KEY,

balance DECIMAL (7,2) NOT NULL

)

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER TOTAL_AI after insert on movement for each row 
begin 
insert into daily_balance values (now(), (select sum(balance) from balance));
end // 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I think you need an event rather than a trigger

Comment: we are working with triggers so i don't really know if it is possible to it with one

Comment: A trigger fires when an insert,update or delete occurs on a table - you cannot run it and you cannot schedule it to run. If you want something to happen every day at specific time then an event (or a cron job) is what you need ,